# How to have lambda as member function's parameter of the template class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, lambda

I have C++ class which is template. it have member function which should take any lamda as parameter;

basically this is what I wanna do:-

```
#include <QFuture>
#include <QFutureWatcher>

template <class T>
class EFuture  {
private:
    QFuture<T> future;
    QFutureWatcher<T> watcher;

public:
    explicit EFuture(QFuture<T> &future);

    void onFinished(void (*f)() );
};


template <class T>
EFuture<T>::EFuture(QFuture<T> &future ): future(future)
{  }

template<class T>
void EFuture<T>::onFinished(void (*f)()){

    QObject::connect(watcher,&QFutureWatcher<T>::finished,f);
    watcher.setFuture(future);
}
```

This have serious restriction as I can't capture anything in lambda which I am passing.
where I try to do something like this:-

```
future->onFinished([someobject](){
   ...
});
```

I get following error:-

```
connectionworker.cpp:106:24: error: no viable conversion from '(lambda at /home/noone/Development/Exatation/Exever/src/connectionworker.cpp:106:24)' to 'void (*)()'
efuture.h:17:28: note: passing argument to parameter 'f' here
```

Comment: Use `void onFinished(std::function<void()> f);` instead

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki thanks. it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only non-capturing and non-generic lambda expressions are convertible to a function pointer. Itself, any lambda expression -- both captureless and capturing ones -- has its own type, known only to the compiler. In such a case, there are two alternatives:

- Use a function template that can deduce the type of the lambda expression:

  ```
  template <typename F>
  void onFinished(F f);
  ```
- Use a type-erasing technique, e.g., `std::function<void()>`:

  ```
  #include <functional>

  void onFinished(std::function<void()> f);
  ```